Book about a post apocalyptic world where the main character, female lead, and friends die trying to save a girl who is immune
I read a book a few years ago where a teen boy and his friends are trying to survive in an apocalyptic world ravaged by a deadly virus. If I remember correctly the virus messes with peoples brains and makes them go crazy.
They encounter a young girl who is immune, and the main character and his female love interest, ultimately sacrifice themselves to save her, sharing a kiss before succumbing to the disease.

By "a few years", do you mean like around 2010? Or somewhere in the 2000s? :) Did it seem like a new book at the time (just showing up on library/bookstore shelves)? Paperback? Hardback? EBook? Online story? How long was it? Do you remember anything about the cover art? You can [edit] any new details into your question.

Maybe The Girl With All the Gifts? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_with_All_the_Gifts

@KlausÆ.Mogensen: Definitely not "The Girl With All the Gifts?". No teenage couple there; and Melanie (the protagonist) is not immune, but was infected so early that her brain could adapt to the infection -- like other young Hungries.
